# Why does running local.phx downgrade the phoenix archive?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

According to [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phx_new/Mix.Tasks.Local.Phx.html), running `mix local.phx` should upgrade the phoenix project generator. Instead, it downgrades it. Is this expected behavior? Why?

```
$ mix phx.new -v                 
Phoenix v1.4.8

$ mix local.phx                  
Found existing entry: /home/me/.mix/archives/phx_new-1.4.8
Are you sure you want to replace it with "https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez"? [Yn]  
* creating /home/me/.mix/archives/phx_new

$ mix phx.new -v
Phoenix v1.3.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that although the latest release at the time of writing is the version you linked to, 1.4.8, the last `phx_new` archive assesible by `local.phx` was produced for 1.3.4. However, there is a [closed bug report on the archive repository](https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/issues/2) with a comment saying that `mix local.phx` should no longer be used, and that the correct way is to install it from hex, where [`1.4.8` is available](https://hex.pm/packages/phx_new/1.4.8):

```
mix archive.install hex phx_new
```

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/3452) to fix this, which has been merged and also back-ported to 1.4, so `local.phx` should use hex by default from the next release (probably version 1.4.9). It will still be necessary to call the above command manually if you're using a pre-1.4.9 version that doesn't include the fix. I added a note to the docs to explain this, which was backported to 1.4 but later removed from master, so I guess this answer will have to suffice after version 1.5

Note that the [phoenix installation guide](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/1.4.8/installation.html#phoenix) doesn't mention `local.phx` and correctly introduces the `archive.install hex phx_new` mix task above.